# Coordinate multiple pairs of slider and numeric input r shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, slider, user-input

I am trying to get the app to display a number of slider/numeric input pairs equal to the initial numeric input. I want each slider and numeric input pair to be coordinated with each other such they always display the same value, like in the example I have below. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Test"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput(inputId = "times", label = "Number of sliders", value = 1, min = 1, max = 100),
            sliderInput(inputId = "Slider1", "Slider1", min = 1, max = 100, value = 50),
            textInput(inputId = "Text1", "Text1", value = 50)
        ),
        mainPanel(uiOutput("plots"))
        
    )
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    list_num <- reactiveValues(value=NULL)
    list_index <- reactiveValues(value=NULL)
    
    
    
    observeEvent(list_num$value, { updateSliderInput(session, "Slider1", max=list_num$value)
        
        
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$Slider1, { print(paste0("Slider1 initial value ", input$Slider1))
        
        list_index$value <- input$Slider1
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$Text1, { print(paste0("Text1 initial value ", input$Text1))
        list_index$value <- max(1, as.numeric(input$Text1))
    })
    
    observeEvent (list_index$value, {
        if (is.na(input$Slider1) | is.na(list_index$value) | list_index$value != input$Slider1) { updateSliderInput(session, "Slider1", value=list_index$value) }
        else {updateTextInput(session, "Text1", value=list_index$value)}
        
    })
    

})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Use [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).  Create a module which handles the co-ordination between each slider and its linked numeric input.  This will minimise your code and keep the main logic of your app uncluttered by the synchronisation logic.

Comment: Maybe use the [shinyChakraSlider](https://github.com/stla/shinyChakraSlider).